# I was using image.asset fluter to load images and it was working fine, all the images were being displayed properly and all of a sudden it shows error

Tags: android, flutter

I changed nothing and all of sudden it says **"Exception caught by image resource service"** I don't know if this has happened to anyone yet.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mentioned in the error where are you getting the expectation. You need to **change** the name of the image having **space** and **capital letter**. for example:

```
images/group339.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the app... sometimes, if you use hot-reload or hot-restart the assets are not loaded.

don't use spaces in your file- or directory-names

(not your question, but maybe a useful hint:

For importing assets you can also use a directory instead:

```
assets:
    -images/
```

)

Answer (score 0):

There is no image as named `Group 3339.png` try to provide correct name. Also It would be better using under-score instead of spaces. And rebuild the app while changing assets.